# Receiving Errors in Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im doing a Netflix clone while watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HW5roUF2RLg&t=8403s)  and im at 2:18:32. This video got shared by Sonny 6 months ago. So its not updated. And im receiving errors when i do the things that shared 6 months ago. at 2:18:32 of video, what should i do in firebase.js and SignupScreen.js to be avoid of errors.

I have tried that before posting this thread. I did this into SignupScreen.js.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import "./SignupScreen.css";

function SignupScreen() {
  const emailRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);

  const register = (e) => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword (auth, emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    alert (errorCode, errorMessage)
  });
};

  const signIn = (e) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword (auth, emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
    .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    alert (errorCode, errorMessage)
  });
  }`
```

And i have tried that in firebase.js :

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBhoDeCtm2ZS3qzr0eWX8IF9-VzvIHAoKQ",
  authDomain: "netflix-clone-31bcf.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "netflix-clone-31bcf",
  storageBucket: "netflix-clone-31bcf.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "615955108716",
  appId: "1:615955108716:web:39e22e96678e1141d3d949"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { signInWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth, auth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword }
export default db;
```

And i got an error when i press to sign in button.

> Error :
> Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).
> FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).

Comment: Can someone help?